# I get a different domain name in google search

Tags: seo, domains, google-search

So here is the story guys please bear with me:

I have registered my domain and deployed my web app and everything is fully functional and working 100%. Then out of the blue I get these SEO scams telling me to pay for SEO. Of course I knew it's a load of bull and I simply deleted all emails. I then wanted to check my web site's ranking so I googled my site's domain and I got my website's pages but with a different domain name! and when I click on them they actually get me to my site while the URL maintains that same weird shady not-domain of mine. I won't be mentioning the domain of my web app or even the one imitating mine since it's a social network still in the works.

I go to godaddy where I registered my domain and then changed my domain to private, and after a few days I checked again and it was gone(the shady domain) and I was like "Thank God, finally". And just now I check again and it's back! what do I do?

The only thing the private domain helped in is giving you a certificate warning when trying to access the shady domain either through google search or directly from URL.

I honestly need help guys, nobody has addressed this problem and I looked all over. Thank you all

Comment: Don't use your domain name,  instead use "site:domain.com". When my site was totally new then Google also show me different website name, it's take some time because Google need more information. By making your domain private does not affect other domain ranking in search, you're misunderstand that. I will just say add more content to your site and let google do it's job. It's take some time.

Comment: It all depends upon how the bad site was created. One trick is simply to point a domain name to your IP address. If you are on a dedicated IP address, this is an easy thing to do. If this is the case, you can simply use canonical tags, use a redirect to test the domain name and redirect to the correct domain name, and include absolute links in your app where you can. If your site is replicated whole-sale, then that can be a bit trickier. If that is the case, file a DMCA complaint immediately with Google so they can know what is going on. ***How exactly is your site being abused?***

Comment: See the question marked as a duplicate, and above comments. We often see similar questions here; sometimes it has to do with shared hosting on a server where a default SSL certificate is installed, and when the other accounts on the server are redirected from HTTP to HTTPS, it results in the domain with the default SSL appearing when crawled by Google. If that sounds like a possibility, then contact your hosting provider for assistance.